# org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | No message key or partition key set

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I'm trying to deploy a simple camel route with kafka, to route the message consumed by one kafka topic to another topic, on jboss fuse, but I am getting the error message "org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.17.0.redhat-630187 | No message key or partition key set". Here is the camel route in blueprint dsl

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint
    xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0
      http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
      <route>
        <from id="_from1" uri="kafka:localhost:9092?topic=test1&amp;groupId=1"/>
          <to uri="kafka:localhost:9092?topic=test2&amp;groupId=1&amp;serializerClass=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"/>
      </route>
    </camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Thanks

Comment: I'm using JBoss Fuse 6.3.0 and Apache Kafka 2.11-1.1.0

Comment: This may be related to https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ENTESB-6775.

Comment: Please use newer version of Fuse 6.3 - you're using GA version.

Comment: Hi @GrzegorzGrzybek, I am using version 6.3.0 from https://developers.redhat.com/products/fuse/download/. Is there a version newer than this?

Comment: Security fixes and patches for Fuse are available through Red Hat Customer Portal.

Comment: You can try finding newer versions of Camel with fixes to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10586 that's what's backported to supported versions of Camel for active subscriptions of Fuse

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek I just downloaded Red Hat JBoss Fuse 6.3 Rollup 3 on Karaf  from the Redhat Customer Portal. But I'm still getting the error "No message key or partition key set" when I deploy the project.

Comment: I'm not that good at camel-kafka/kafka itself, but I see missing kafka.KEY property.

Comment: If you are using a Kafka cluster based on 1.1.0, JBoss Fuse 6.3.x is based on a different version. The Kafka's Camel version used in Fuse 6.3.x is not 1.1.0, but an old one.